# Resizing Animated GIF images with ruby?

Tags: ruby, image-processing, rmagick

I am trying to resize a GIF image to different sizes. I am using RMagick library in ruby. But it seems for some gif images the file size increases even when I am downsizing GIF. And I am resizing the image image in same aspect ratio. Here is the my code.

```
require 'rmagick'
path = "/path/to/file/"
s_image = "image.gif" # image is 320*320
t_image = "t.gif"
file_name = path+s_image
file = File.new(file_name)
list = Magick::ImageList.new.from_blob file.read
list = list.coalesce.remap
list.each do |x|
  x.resize_to_fill!(256,256)
end
File.open("#{path+t_image}", 'wb') { |f| f.write list.to_blob }
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Could you give an example image that grows larger. My best guess is that you start with a low colour count, but the re-size will create merged colours for some pixels, which will either become dithered in new image (reducing RLE efficiency) or require larger palette from original.

Comment: Here are the example files
Source file - https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/47897449/s_image.gif (602 x 429)
Target file - https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/47897449/t_image.gif (301 x 214)
Sorry but I am not an expert in this. But if you could point to something or may be elaborate in detail what can I do.

Comment: It has nothing to do with Ruby

Comment: @Michael Szyndel: It does relate to Ruby in as much as this is coded in Ruby, and the solution is available in Ruby. I don't wish to undo your edit - but now you can see the question and answer contain only Ruby code, would you agree the Ruby tag is now appropriate? At the very least this would put automatic syntax highlighting back on easier than me going in and tagging both code fragments

Comment: Neil, your question, and the problem OP is describing has nothing to do with Ruby simply because no matter in what language you execute ImageMagick, it still will be... ImageMagick (here invoked via RMagick). just as your great answer explains.

Comment: On the other hand I must agree that it is like saying that "how to sum records in rails" is just mysql/postgres/etc. question. Adding the tag again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The image you linked consisted of 35 frames. It had also been optimised, so that after than the first frame, each frame only contains the pixels that are different. Most of the pixels are transparent, because very little moves. This is common situation with animated gifs - they can be made relatively efficient (in terms of file size) if there are not too many changes or camera movement.

In addition, each frame size is the minimum rectangle necessary to contain all the changing pixels, so it varies from frame-to-frame.

You can see this clearly, if you load the original image in e.g. The GIMP, and inspect the individual layers.

If you do that with your converted image, can also see that your code renders out each frame in full, in order to re-size accurately. As a side effect of this, it increases the file size. Reducing the image x,y to half should mean your output file size is roughly 1/4 of the original. However, turning each frame from just a few pixels difference to the full frame multiplies the size dramatically. As there are 35 frames, this more than makes up for the smaller width and height.

Luckily, ImageMagick (and Rmagick bindings in Ruby) includes a function for re-optimising the GIF back to layers with only the differences stored as visible pixels. You need to add a  call to this `optimize_layers` method to allow your code to have a lower file size. In addition, for best file size you need to stop using `.remap` which is altering pixel values enough that the optimiser does not work.

```
require 'rmagick'
path = "/path/to/file/"
s_image = "s_image.gif" # image is 320*320
t_image = "t_image.gif"
file_name = path+s_image
file = File.new(file_name)
list = Magick::ImageList.new.from_blob file.read

# This renders out each GIF frame in full, prior to re-sizing
# Note I have removed the .remap because it alters pixel values
# between frames, making it hard to optimise
list = list.coalesce

list.each do |x|
  x.resize_to_fill!(256,256)
end

# Re-optimize the GIF frames
list = list.optimize_layers( Magick::OptimizeLayer )

File.open("#{path+t_image}", 'wb') { |f| f.write list.to_blob }
```

Comment: Using the CompareClearLayer, animation didn't work, but I used the OptimizeLayer and it worked for me.

Comment: @Narenda Rajput: I must have got confused while testing, I have adjusted the answer, thank you. It works, and the file size is smaller, but the result is a little disappointing on my setup. Logically it should be possible to get a much smaller file size, but I am not sure what else should change to achieve that

Comment: @Narenda Rajput: Remove the `.remap`, it is altering colour subtly and  making it impossible to optimize the frames.

Comment: If you need the `.remap`, then do `list = list.optimize_layers( Magick::OptimizeLayer ).remap` - i.e. *after* you have restored the optimisation