# Rails paperclip increasing GIF size

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, gif

I have a rails app that allows users to upload GIFs. But I find that the resized images are larger in size than the original upload.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21910837/resizing-animated-gif-images-with-ruby) is what I found after some searching on the internet.

But how do I implement this with paperclip and rails?

My model app/models/gif.rb

```
class GIF < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_attached_file :upload, :styles => { :medium => "500x500#", :thumb => "150x150#" }, :default_url => "default.gif"

end
```

I don't have any config.paperclip_defaults set in any of the configuration files.

Comment: You are supposed to have a go and then post your code here so someone can correct you.

Answer (score 2):

So here's what I did.

```
has_attached_file :upload,
  :styles => {
    :medium => "500x500#",
    :thumb => "150x150#"
  },
  :default_url => "default.gif",
  :convert_options => {
    :medium => "-layers optimize",
    :thumb => "-layers optimize"
  }
```